# How to export a list of recently opened files from Office:MAC? 2011?

Tags: ms-office

I recently inherited some old mac machines and was told to look for anything important on the before formatting them.

One of the things that is installed on these machines is Office:MAC 2011, and everytime I open one of these documents I'm concerned that another falls off the recently opened list.

I'd like to save the list of recent files some how so that I don't loose anymore recently opened documents.

Is it possible to somehow export this list so I can view the list without destroying the list?

Comment: You could take a screenshot of the list

Comment: :p No, I want something I can search the text of.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but it's complicated.

The recent documents for all Microsoft office products are stored in a preferences file (plist) in each users's library:

`~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.office.plist`

This file is in standard plist format, and can be viewed using the plist viewer built into Xcode.  If you open it up it will look something like this:

[image: microsoft plst]

The list of recent items for each application is stored in the key `File MRU`.  The example above is for Word, which corresponds to the `MSWD` code.  Each document compromises one numbered item under this plist key.

As you can see, unfortunately the values for these keys are binary encoded, not plain text, so you need to paste the Value strings into a Hex editor to see the file names and paths.  (I use [HexFiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) .)

[image: hex viewer]

**Bottom Line:** Copy the `com.microsoft.office.plist` file to a safe location.  With some elbow grease, you can pull all the recent files out of this document.

You could also check out [this Python script](http://az4n6.blogspot.com/2013/08/ms-office-recent-docs-plist-parser.html) that does some of this parsing automatically, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

The location of the property list with the recently opened files has changed since BringMyCakeBack's answer was posted. They are now kept in `~/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/Data/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.Word.securebookmarks.plist`. The file is in a binary format that Xcode understands. See also [here](https://www.tech-otaku.com/mac/removing-entries-microsoft-office-apps-recent-files-lists-macos/).

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research there is no way to do this. However, what you could do is:

1. Change the number of files that appear in the list

   or
2. Pin the files to the list

See [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/customize-the-list-of-recently-used-files-HA010354236.aspx#BM2) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a running list of documents you are going to open moving forward, add this macro to your Normal.dot

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    Dim ff As Long
    Dim logpath As String

    logpath = MacScript("return (path to desktop) as string") & "autoopen_log.txt"

    ff = FreeFile
    Open logpath For Append As #ff
    Print #ff, ActiveDocument.FullName
    Close #ff
End Sub
```

It will log the path of every file you open in Word to the specified text file on your desktop. You can just reopen the existing recent files to add them to the log.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing this in Swift and not even using it (because the format changed in Office 15), but if anyone else still needs it:

```swift
import Foundation

func getMRUList(forApp: String) -> [String]? {
    guard let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().persistentDomainForName("com.microsoft.office") else {
        NSLog("Unable to find Office defaults")
        return nil
    }

    guard let mruList = defaults["14\\File MRU\\" + forApp ] as? [NSDictionary] else {
        NSLog("Unable to find recent documents for Office application \(forApp)")
        return nil
    }

    return mruList.flatMap { (mruItem: NSDictionary) in
        guard let mruFileAliasData = mruItem["File Alias"] as? NSData else {
            NSLog("Unable to extract file alias from MRU item \(mruItem)")
            return nil
        }
        do {
            let mruFileBookmarkData = CFURLCreateBookmarkDataFromAliasRecord(nil, mruFileAliasData).takeRetainedValue()
            let mruFileURL = try NSURL.init(byResolvingBookmarkData: mruFileBookmarkData, options: NSURLBookmarkResolutionOptions(), relativeToURL: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: nil)
            return mruFileURL.path
        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("Unable to resolve file alias for MRU item \(mruFileAliasData): \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}

if let mruList = getMRUList("MSWD") {
    print(NSString.init(data: try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(mruList, options: NSJSONWritingOptions()), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
}
```

You can replace `MSWD` with the creator of another Office 14 app (e.g. `PPT3` for PowerPoint, `XCEL` for Excel) as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to produce a list of Office documents that have been opened on this Mac, just create a Spotlight search with the following criteria:

[image]

This gives me a list of every Microsoft file that has been opened (in the last 20 years). You can then sort the list by date.

You can specify each exact Office file type individually, of course.