# Where does Pages store its list of recently opened documents?

Tags: macbook-pro, pages, plist, library

I'm currently creating a [raycast](https://raycast.com) extension for quickly opening recently opened Pages documents.
Now, I have to find a way to access the documents and their pathnames. I
tried following [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/421589/506616) and stumbled across `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iWork.Pages/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iWork.Pages.plist`. This plist file contains a key named `TSARecentOpenedDocumentTimestamps` which corresponds to an array of timestamps of when I opened pages documents.

However, when using Xcode's built inplist search tool, I could not find any arrays of recently opened file paths or names. I also tried renaming the file to `com.apple.iWork.Pages.old.plist` and then quit and reopened pages. After it opened, I was faced with the "welcome to pages" screen, like when I first opened it after getting my MacBook. However, I tried going to `file -> open recent` in the menu bar and found that my recently opened file names were still there, but greyed out. Therefore, the recently opened files could not have been stored in that plist.

A raycast extension exists for opening recently opened Visual Studio Code projects, so I forked the code to see how. It reads from a database located at `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb` with the following SQL query `SELECT json_extract(value, '$.entries') as entries FROM ItemTable WHERE key = 'history.recentlyOpenedPathsList'`. However, while trying to find a similar file for pages, I noticed that it does not even have a folder in `~/Library/Application Support` with its data.

I have absolutely no idea where Pages could store this data, and without knowing where, I can't build this extension. So does anyone know where this data is stored? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native Mac applications delegate this functionality to Apple's frameworks.

### AppKit and NSDocumentController

For document based Mac applications, recent documents are handled by Apple's AppKit  `NSDocumentController` class. Applications can call the [`NSDocumentController recentDocumentsURLs`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocumentcontroller/1514976-recentdocumenturls) method to access this list.

This means the list is managed by macOS and is not expected to be read directly.

### Launch Services

Below `NSDocumentController`, the recent documents are managed by [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/launch_services):

> macOS Launch Services is an API that enables a running app to open other apps or their document files, similar to the Finder or the Dock. Using Launch Services, an app can perform such tasks as:
>
> - ...
> - Maintain and update the contents of the Recent Items menu

See [sharedfilelistd](https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/sharedfilelistd.8.html) and [sfltool](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/sfltool/) for related commands.

#### `com.apple.sharedfilelist`

Listed in the related files section of `sharedfilelistd`'s manual page is this file pattern:

```
ls ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/*
```

These files store the recent documents per application. They appear to be encoded by [`NSCoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoder) and written as a Binary Property List files. Passing a file to the `file`  command confirms the base format of `Apple binary property list`.

Comment: Thanks, I found the file `~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments/com.apple.iwork.pages.sfl2` However, sfltool is failing when I try to archive the file and outputs: `CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed a URL which has no scheme`.  What exactly is an NSEncoded property list? I know what a standard property list is, but I don't know how to decode it or turn it into a standard Plist

Comment: Sorry, but the documentation wasn't that helpful for me because I know absolutely nothing about objective-c. How can I decode the file by making an NSCoder in the terminal? The pmutil command did work by the way, but the file is pretty useless until I figure out how to decode it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I created the new question. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/464870/how-to-decode-nscoder